# How do I set a fixed shutter speed on a Canon Rebel T7?

Tags: canon, shutter-priority

I am having trouble with keeping the same shutter speed between shooting photos? I am using a Canon Rebel T7. I'm not sure where in the menu I need to go to correct this issue. I am new to photography and need all the help I can get.

I am in Manual mode. If I set my shutter speed to say 1/30s and take my photo, when I go to shoot a similar shot right away, I have to reset the shutter speed again.

I guess what I'm asking is can I do something to keep that shutter speed the same until I decide to change it?

Comment: That camera has 4 main modes: P (Program), Tv (Shutter Priority), Av (Aperture Priority) and M (Manual).  Both P and Av modes will vary the shutter speed to suit the exposure.  Do you know what mode you are shooting photos in?  And do you have the manual?

Comment: I am shooting in Manual Mode

Comment: OK, then I don't think I fully understand what the problem is that you are having.  Can you give a concrete example of what you are experiencing?

Comment: I set my shutter speed to say 1/30, take my photo and when I go to shoot a similar shot right away, I have to reset the shutter speed again...I guess what I'm asking is can I do something to keep that shutter speed the same until I decide to change it

Comment: That sounds more like you're in Av or P mode. Check in the viewfinder, to the left of your shutter speed, does it say "M"?  In M mode, neither the aperture nor the shutter speed should change unless you change it. Are you accidentally turning the control wheel under your right forefinger?

Comment: Can you photos of you rear screen in manual mode after pressing on the "Q" button, just before taking a picture and just after (obviously once the photo preview is gone)?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to reset the shutter speed again"? What if you don't? What happens then? What shutter speed is used?

Comment: Personally, I also don't recommend Manual mode for someone new to photography. Others might. Do you understand the exposure triangle, and how the various exposure modes differ? What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to set a shutter speed of 1/30?

Answer (score 2):

Turn off Auto Exposure Bracketing (AEB) under the 'Shooting 2' (Red Tab 2) Menu → 'Expo.comp./AEB' setting.

You can also access Exposure Compensation/AEB settings via the 'Quick Control Screen' by pressing the 'Q' button.

It's covered on pages 116-119 of the [EOS Rebel T7/1500D Instruction Manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300029810/01/eos-rebelt7-1500d-im-en.pdf)